# PostgreSQL unnest(array_agg(x))

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

Lets say we have a table 1

```
1 2 3
a x 10
a y 20
b z 50
```

As result of the select we want to get the following:

```
1 2 3
a x 30
a y 30
b z 50
```

At least the sum of the lines where column 1 is equal. I do the following select and it is working. But the select looks ugly, is there a smarter solution?

```
SELECT 1, UNNEST(ARRAY_AGG(2)), SUM(3) FROM table1
GROUP BY (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a window sum instead:

```
select col1, col2, sum(col3) over(partition by col1) col3
from mytable
```